# Completely remove Rspec, Capybara & Factory-Girl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, factory-bot

I've been following the Rails tutorial but decided that ultimately I want to remove Rspec, Capybara and Factory-Girl gems as well as all the generated files, however I have no clue how to do this. I know there have been a couple of similar questions posted here but I couldn't find a real answer anywhere. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove them from your `gemfile`. Then run `bundle install` from the command line. That is it. As far as the generated files you will have to remove them manually. You can use `rm -r spec/requests`for the directories or `rm spec/requests/name_of_spec.rb` for each individual file at the command line. Let me know if you need more help

Comment: Ok, thanks. I thought there was another way but it seems I'm going to have to remove /spec manually.